# How to run a class if a condition is true?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I want to run the full class if a condition is true. I can do this by putting the full code inside a if block.

```
is_active = True

class testClass():
    if is_active:
        print("Hello World")
        def func():
            print("this is a function")
        def func2():
            print("this is a another function")
```

But don't want to put the full code inside an `if` block. I want to do something like this, exiting for a condition. What we do by `return` in functions.

```
class testClass():
    if is_active is False:
        #Exit the class(like return in a function)
    print("Hello World")
    def func():
        print("this is a function")
    def func2():
        print("this is a another function")
```

My code looks something like this.

```
active = True    
class class1(parent_class):    
    if active is False:
        # Exit the class(like return in a function)
    print("Hello World")
    def func(self):
        print("this is a function")
    def func2(self):
        print("this is a another function")

class class2(class1):
    # Inherited class1. 
    # class1 will only work if active is True

obj = class2()
```

Please help

Comment: You want to give the class methods only sometimes? That's very odd. You'd be better off having separate classes.

Comment: I don't like any of this. Interfaces should not -in general- be conditional.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by doing this?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. I suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding about classes. In any case, there is no equivalent to `break` or `return` in a class block, so you *could* use `if` (although again, that makes absolutely no sense). Why **don't** you want to use `if`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i've edited the question. Please check.

Comment: i think you might be asking a really precise feature. Python has loads of stuff but not anything. You can always put all the functions inside an if block or put an if block at the end deleting the functions (NOT the class). Or maybe use different classes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of not declaring the methods you could delete them!

```
active = False
class myclass:
    def myfunct1():
        print("I am function 1")
    def myfunct2():
        pass
    def myfunct3():
        print("I am function 3!")
    if not active:
        del(myfunct3)

myclass.myfunct1()
myclass.myfunct2()
myclass.myfunct3()
```

If you run this you'll get:

```
I am function 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    myclass.myfunct3()
AttributeError: type object 'myclass' has no attribute 'myfunct3'
```

Change the first line to:
`active = True`

And you'll get:

```
I am function 1
I am function 3!
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: To clarify: you are declaring the functions to then delete them if active is False

Comment: I can't delete the class. Because I need it later. 

The question has been edited. Please check.

Comment: you are not deleting the class, you are deleting the functions

Answer (score 0):

well, if you do not want to use if to not declare the functions or to delete them you can always add them!

Example:

```
def function1():
    print("I'm function 1")
print("[LOG] Declared function1 {}".format(function1))


if input("Active? [y/n]").lower() == "y":
    active = True
else:
    active = False

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        if active:
            self.function1 = function1
        print("[LOG] Class initalized")
    def function2(self):
        print("I'm function 2")

print("[LOG] Declared MyClass {}".format(MyClass))

obj = MyClass()
obj.function2()
obj.function1()
```

Output (when yes):

```
myuser@UbuntuVm:~/Desktop$ python test.py 
[LOG] Declared function1 <function function1 at 0x7f53cd4450d0>
Active? [y/n]y
[LOG] Declared MyClass <class '__main__.MyClass'>
[LOG] Class initalized
I'm function2
I'm function 1
```

Output (when no):

```
myuser@UbuntuVm:~/Desktop$ python test.py 
[LOG] Declared function1 <function function1 at 0x7f9c54c090d0>
Active? [y/n]n
[LOG] Declared MyClass <class '__main__.MyClass'>
[LOG] Class initalized
I'm function 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 23, in <module>
    obj.function1()
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'function1'
```

I think that's what you meant, you could even change the functions when active is False.